# Django template not receiving variables

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I am writing a django template `Configuration_Detail.html` and it renders correctly on the relevant urls. It does not, however, take any variables whatsoever from the view class. I had a very similar template `Configuration_List.html` which worked fine, though that was a `ListView` not a `DetailView`.

Configuration_Detail.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans 'MySite Database' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'MySite Database: Current Instrumentation Configuration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
Here is some text {{name}} with a variable in the middle.
{% endblock %}
```

The page renders the title bar fine, but the content block becomes "Here is some text with a variable in the middle."
I believe it should be taking the variable `{{ name }}` from here.

views.py:

```
class ConfigurationDetail(DetailView):
model = Configuration    
def getname(self):
    name = 'debug'
    return name
```

But it does not...
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Edited to add:
Models.py - Configuration:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False)
author = models.ForeignKey(User)  
created = models.DateField("date created",auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateField("date modified",auto_now=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
drawing =  models.ForeignKey(Drawing,blank=True,null=True)
instruments = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

The `get_context_data()` method is using `ctx['author'] = Configuration.author`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView), an `object` variable is added in the context which points to the database object for which the view is being rendered. So in your template you can do:

```
{% block content %}
   Here is some text {{ object.author.get_full_name }}
   with a variable in the middle.
{% endblock %}
```

The [`get_full_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_full_name) method is from the User object.

Comment: Further to this, if I try to pass a record specific item using this method, it fails. I was trying to pass `author` to the template and got `<django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x1084fba50>`

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly you need to access a model property from within a template, but for that is sufficient to do `{{ configuration.author }}` without modifying the context data at all!

the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) puts in the context the selected model, accessible with the dot notation.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do. Unfortunately, it seems not to work.

Comment: edit the question with the non-working code in which you use `{{ configuration.author }}`. btw, the `getname()` function is useless ;)

Comment: `getname` had a more complex job, but was set to pass a definite output for testing purposes. I originally suspected there may be something wrong with my method. When you ask for the non-operational code, do you mean the template?

Comment: yes i mean all the code you are talking about. i'd suggest you to leave the view as simpler as it can be, and put the `getname` complex job in the model, as a [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods). this way you can access to is as a template variable!